# introjs Highlighted area in wrong position. Chrome only

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, intro.js

Added introjs to the site I'm working on and ran into two issues.

First: The highlighted area was overlaying the content underneath. I added a position absolute in the introjs.css file, which fixed this issue.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZHoq.jpg)

Second: The highlight area is out of position on Chrome. I think both issues are to do with the fixed position on that bootstrap navbar.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmWgo.jpg)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be chrome not being able to handle zoom in css.